# After upgrade from magento 2.3 to magento 2.3.5 page error message not showing while FPC is enabled

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Only Page error messages are not showing at the frontend, When I disable the Full page cache then a page error message appears correctly. Also want to inform that we are using smartwave porto theme at the frontend. Please guide me on this asap. Please check the screenshot

Tried Method:

1. Checked with default magento luma theme and disabled the third party modules

Looking forward to hearing from as soon as possible

Comment: can you add the screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem.

Looks like the messages tag is hidden on the home page with the following code in the custom.css file:

```
.cms-index-index .page.messages {
display: none;
}
```

I don't know if this is a bug or a design feature or if it can be disabled/enabled. I've corrected it by adding the code:

```
.cms-index-index .page.messages {
display: block;
}
```